# Accessing domain control panel at yahoo

Tags: domain-name

A friend of mine purchased a domain name about 8-9 years ago. Time came to switch hosts and change DNS settings, but we can't find where the control panel now is.

Where I thought the panel is (it is for me) she gets a message saying "sorry, there are no Yahoo Small Business services associated with the Yahoo ID so-and-so"

I asked her to dig up original email regarding the domain purchase in hope of some clues, but this is really strange. Any ideas?

Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.melbourneit.com

Registrar URL: http://www.melbourneit.com.au

Tech Name: YahooDomains TechContact

Tech Organization: Yahoo! Inc

Tech Email: domain.tech@YAHOO-INC.COM

Answer (score 0):

Which domain is it? If your uncomfortable answering that question. Check out the who-is and see who the registrar for that domain is. Contact their support and let us know your findings!

**Edits after additional information:**

I'm at a loss, and apologize for the bad answer. However, you may try going directly through melbourneit.com.au and see if you can access the control panel there.

Comment: I did, turns out yahoo seems to have this issue with recently purchased domains also. We're in the process of contacting them. Will post the results, what a pain this is.

Comment: Verified the registrar is yahoo. Correct?

Comment: Added some details about that to question

Comment: is it possible to login at http://www.melbourneit.com.au/?

Comment: I think she tried over the phone and got nowhere, but we'll keep trying

Comment: I kicked me back tot the 'reseller', that being yahoo

Comment: Vendor issue. Let us know the resolution